# Get beginning balance based on selected month in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate beginning balance for the selected month. for example, I'm having a list of pre-allocated serial numbers/ids/rows 1000 to 1999. In February I'm using 800 numbers (from id 1000-1799). Thus, my next months beginning balance would be 200.
In my DB I'm having three relevant columns: id, created_date and updated_date.
If I use only 50 numbers in March (1800-1849), then beginning balance for April is 150 (I already used up 850 of the pre-allocated 1000 ids). How to query the DB to fetch the number of remaining pre-allocated ids?

Comment: I think you need to modify your question little more.

Comment: Yeah better to show your db strucure and some data

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Can you please tell me  how to show db strucure and some data.i'm a new bee

Answer (score 0):

This example is based on the amount of information you provided and assumes you don't need to filter by user id or any other data, but that you do have a numeric row id.

`SELECT (1000 - COUNT(*)) AS balance FROM table_name WHERE id BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999`

If that is not the case, then please add the result of the 
`explain table_name` command, where you substitute `table_name` with the actual name of the table.

Comment: `select * from official_receipt_numbers where (visa_id=0) and month(created_time)=$pre_month and year(created_time)=$getyear `.                                I need to fetch the unused number from list of serial numbers in the table based on updated_time